# There exist a sequence $Z_n$ with $Z_n \to Z_0$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ has an Essential Singularity at $Z_0$. Then there exist a sequence $Z_n$ with $Z_n \to Z_0$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(Z_n)| = \infty$

Here two cases arise

- If there exist a nbd of $Z_0$ such that $f$ is bounded, then $f$ is a removable Singularity which is a contradiction.
- If any nbd of $Z_0$ $f$ is unbounded, then any nbd $S_{1/n} (Z_0)$ , there exist $Z_n \in S_{1/n}(Z_0) $ such that $|f(Z_n)| > n$, where $n \in \mathbb N$,Thus $Z_n \to Z_0$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(Z_n)| = \infty$.

My question :

> > If $f$ has a pole of order n at $Z_0$, Is there exist a sequence  $Z_n$ with $Z_n \to Z_0$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(Z_n)| = \infty$ . If not exist, why it is not exist.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If $Z_0$ is pole then $\lim\limits_{z\to Z_0}f(z) = \infty$. If $\lim\limits_{z\to Z_0}f(z) = \infty$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(Z_n) = \infty$ for any sequence $Z_n\to Z_0$.

Comment: Nikita Evseev: Thanks , I had forgotten this result.